# Paypal developer site SSL error : I need a list of error codes

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

The link https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/  fails with ans SSL error (as do many links in that area.)

Does anyone have a list of error codes in the 58xxxx range?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not having any issues loading that page.  I don't see any errors listed that start with 58, though.

Comment: I can also load any of those pages error free. If you post the complete error code and perhaps a little background I will try to define it.

Answer (score 0):

I could only find a record of 2 error codes that begin with "58". I found them on [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/GetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/)...

580001 Invalid request:

580022 Invalid request parameter: payKey with value